# Can you pass non-string objects from getStaticPaths() in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Apparently, Next.js forces you to provide a **string** parameter called `slug` inside `getStaticPaths()` if the file from which it is called is named **[slug].js**.

**However, it would be very convenient for me to pass an entire object from `getStaticPaths()` instead of just its slug.**

I am trying to do the following inside my **[slug].js** file:

```
export default function Expression({ expression, definitions }) {
    return <div>{expression.expression}</div>
}

// Specify possible dynamic routes to pre-render.
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dictionary/expressions')
    const expressions = await response.json()
    const paths = expressions.map(expression => ({
        params: { expression: expression, slug: expression.slug }}))
    return { paths, fallback: false }
}

// Fetch definitions.
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const expression = params.expression
    const response = await fetch(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dictionary/${expression.slug}`)
    const definitions = await response.json()
    return { props: { expression, definitions } }
}
```

The error I get comes from the `fetch()` call of `getStaticProps()` and says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined

It seems that Next.js rejects anything inside `params` that's not a string called "slug." Is there a way to pass non-string objects named whatever I want from `getStaticPaths()` to `getStaticProps()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its documents

> `params` contains the route parameters for pages using dynamic routes. For example, if the page name is `[id].js` , then params will look like `{ id: ... }`.

So the answer is no, you can only access `slug` from your params. Btw, why don't you make a call to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dictionary/expressions` and did a comparison with your `slug`? Cause those ones is executed in build time, it won't affect to your website loading speed.